# How to sequentially aggregate the content of a dask Bag?

Tags: python, dask

I would like to sequentially aggregate the content of a partitioned collection with an aggregation function that is not associative, therefore I cannot use `Bag.fold` or `Bag.reduction`.

There is `Bag.accumulate` that seems to do this operation, but it returns a bag with some per-partition intermediate results instead of just the final aggregate:

```
>>> import dask.bag as db
>>>
>>> def collect(acc, e):
...     if acc is None:
...         acc = list()
...     acc.append(e)
...     return acc
...
>>> b = db.from_sequence(range(10), npartitions=3)
>>> b.accumulate(collect, initial=None).compute()
[None,
 [0, 1, 2, 3],
 [0, 1, 2, 3],
 [0, 1, 2, 3],
 [0, 1, 2, 3],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

Basically I am only interested in the last element of the `accumulate` output and I don't want to keep a copy of the intermediate steps in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bag doesn't currently have a sequential reduction operation, but it could.  A simple way to accomplish this today would be to use use `accumulate` as you have above, but only ask for the last element of the last partition.  We can do this relatively easily by converting the bag to delayed values using [Bag.to_delayed](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/bag-api.html#dask.bag.Bag.to_delayed)

```
acc = b.accumulate(collect, initial=None)
partitions = acc.to_delayed()
partitions[-1][-1].compute()
```

Comment: Indeed I thought about `to_delayed` (or just writing a everything with `delayed` calls in a loop from the start) but I was wondering if there was not a more "dask-ish" way to do it.

Comment: We should really have a `Bag.reduce` method for cases like this.  In general I would say that switching out to dask.delayed is the "dask-ish" way.  No tool can anticipate every situation that users encounter.  "Use dask.delayed" is probably the answer to about 30% of #dask-labeled stack overflow questions.